# React native. losing context of this in touchable highlight on press.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to add a TouchableHighlight component to a row in a list view.

The onPress function is throwing an undefined error in the code below. It works outside of the list view.

I suspect this is because I'm losing context of `this` but unsure how to fix. Anyone able to help?

```
export default class ConversationsList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._handleChangePage = this._handleChangePage.bind(this);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(Coversations.chats)
    };
  }

  _handleChangePage(chat) {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: 'foo',
      component: Chat,
      passProps: {
        chat: chat
      }
    });
  }


  renderRow(chat){
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this._handleChangePage.bind(this, chat) }>
          <View>
             /* more content removed */
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I also suspect that I shouldn't really be doing things this way, that my component should be structured differently, so it is passed the press handler as a prop perhaps. any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare another variable globally like

```
var _this;
```

initialise it in render method

```
render:function(){
 _this = this;

 return(
 ...
 )
}
```

and use it in your touchableHightlight

```
renderRow(chat){
return (
  <View>
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => _this._handleChangePage(chat) }>
      <View>
         /* more content removed */
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to read this [helpful article](https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/)

```
export default class ConversationsList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(Coversations.chats)
    };
  }

  _handleChangePage = () => {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: 'foo',
      component: Chat,
      passProps: {
        chat: this
      }
    });
  }


  renderRow = (chat) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={ this._handleChangePage }>
          <View>
             /* more content removed */
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```